# JavaScript - Is it possible to limit the results given by a forEach loop?

Tags: javascript, foreach

I have a very long JSON `array` that I fetch using a `forEach` loop where I need to display only the last 5 elements.

```
  array.forEach(showOnlyFiveElements => {
   //only 5 elements should be show here
  });
```

Can't it be done using a forEach ? Or I should go for something different?

Comment: `array.slice(0, 5).forEach`

Comment: you can use if inside forEach

Comment: Use [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for_statement) starting at the end and counting down (i--) with correct condition

Comment: @Andreas `.slice(-5)....`. :)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You could use [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) with negative value for the last items.

```
array.slice(-5).forEach()
```

Comment: I don't know how I forgot that. Thanks, for sure, it works ;)

Comment: For the first 5 items, can I do `slice(5)` ?

Comment: @RalphDavidAbernathy, the first parameter is the start index, if positive, it starts from this index. that means you need to take `array.slice(0, 5)` .