# Can I set a limit on the forEach command? [TypeScript]

Tags: typescript

With the forEach command, I pull the team players in the lobby in my web-based game. For a feature in my game, I want to get the id of the first player in the opposing team. How can I do this over my existing code?

The code below is getting the id of the list of all the players in the opposing team. I just want to get the id of the first player in the opposing team. I hope I was able to explain what I mean.

```
lobby.players
    .filter((player) => player.team !== team)
    .forEach((player) => {
        socketServer.to(player.id).emit('GameRound', Role.Watcher);
    });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript - Is it possible to limit the results given by a forEach loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43737065/javascript-is-it-possible-to-limit-the-results-given-by-a-foreach-loop)

Answer (score 0):

you don't need a loop here if you just want to get the id of the first player, check the example below:

```js
const player = lobby.players.filter((player) => player.team !== team)
socketServer.to(player[0].id).emit('GameRound', Role.Watcher);
```